# JS inputs.every() not evaluating to true even though both elements are true

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I currently have two input fields `email` and `text` in my **HTML** code. Inside **Javascript**, I am attempting to do a `reportValidity()` for both before moving on to the next step in a multi-step form. For some reason, if I do a `inputs.some(input => {console.log(input.reportValidity())})` I get the values `true` and `true` for both form inputs when appropriate.

After removing the `console.log()`, I am expecting the next line and `const allValid` to be equals to `true` but when i `console.log(allValid)` it returns `false`.

I have omitted some things from the `JavaScript` block below, but when I do a `console.log()` of `input` from `inputs`, it logs the correct input fields.

**HTML Code**

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const multiStepForm = document.querySelector("[data-multi-step]")
const formSteps = [...multiStepForm.querySelectorAll("[data-step]")]
const inputs = [...formSteps[currentStep].querySelectorAll("input")]

console.log("Each run starts here")
inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.reportValidity()))
const allValid = inputs.every(input => {input.reportValidity()})
console.log(allValid)
```

When ran, inside the `console` my log is

```
This run starts here.
true x 2 <- from reportValidity()
false <- from const AllValid
```

Comment: Tried your code and I get `true` every time for `password`

Comment: After some more troubleshooting, I realised I misjudged the intial problem. I am able to get `true` for both forms, however the `const allValid` still evaluates to `false`. I have removed the `console.log()` statements from the `forEach` loop but it still evaluates to `false`. Am slightly confused as I believed when both values are `true`, `some` should evaluate to `true` as well

Comment: You don't return anything inside `every` remove `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove a pair of `{}` as I was not returning anything.

**JavaScript**

```
const multiStepForm = document.querySelector("[data-multi-step]")
const formSteps = [...multiStepForm.querySelectorAll("[data-step]")]
const inputs = [...formSteps[currentStep].querySelectorAll("input")]

console.log("Each run starts here")
inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.reportValidity()))
const allValid = inputs.every(input => input.reportValidity()) //Remove {} here
console.log(allValid)
```